# TypeError: book.isEqual is not a function

Tags: typescript, function, firebase, typeerror

A method defined in a Class is not recognized as a function when called in an other class.

file : models/book.model.ts

```
export class Book {
    constructor(public title: string, public author: string) {
    }

    isEqual (other: Book ): boolean {
    return (this === other);
    }
}
```

file : services/books.service.ts

```
import { Book } from '../models/book.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import DataSnapshot = firebase.database.DataSnapshot;

export class BooksService {
    books = [new Book ('', '')]
    booksSubject = new Subject<Book[]>();

    constructor() {
    this.getBooks();
    }

    emitBooks() {
    this.booksSubject.next(this.books);
    }

    getBooks() {
    firebase.database().ref('/books')
        .on('value', 
            (data: DataSnapshot) => 
            {
                this.books = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
                this.emitBooks(); /
            }
        );
    }

    indexOfBook (book: Book) {
    const bookIndex = this.books.findIndex(
        (a_book) => {return book.isEqual (a_book)}
    );
    return bookIndex;
    }
```

I would like to call 'book.isEqual' method of Book class in class BooksService. 
book.isEqual is not recognized as a function, why ?

Comment: If it's a TypeError, that suggests you're encountering the error at runtime and it has nothing to do with TypeScript typings. Is that correct? If so, this also suggests that `book` is not actually an instance of the `Book` class. Have you ensured that it's actually a `Book`?

Comment: Could you add the error log ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but I'm pretty sure that if you're retrieving the books from a database, they're not going to automatically have an `isEqual` method. I suspect that's why you're having an issue.

Comment: I am also not familiar with firebase. I suspect the problem comes from there.
May be there : 
this.books = data.val() ? data.val() : [];

How to tell firebase that books are an array of Book ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created this stackblitz project https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-stackoverflow, it works fine, you can check it

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

// These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import DataSnapshot = firebase.database.DataSnapshot;

const config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAh-EgWckq1oexuxQ0vVSbKE6jIOGDPcu4",
    authDomain: "yallswall.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://yallswall.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "yallswall",
    storageBucket: "yallswall.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "109317481518",
    appId: "1:109317481518:web:14342c0b3d54017f"
};

class Book {
    constructor(public title: string, public author: string) {
    }

    isEqual (other: Book): boolean {
     return (this === other);
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li class="text" *ngFor="let book of books">
        {{book.title}} : {{book.author}}, {{book.isEqual(book)}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  books: Book[] = [];

  constructor() {
   firebase.initializeApp(config);
   this.getBooks();
  }

  getBooks() {
    firebase.database().ref('books')
      .on('value', (data: DataSnapshot) => {

        this.books = data && data.val().map(bookLike => new Book(bookLike.title, bookLike.author)) || [];

        //the code below works too
        //this.books = [];
        //data && data.forEach(e => {
        //  const bookLike = e.val();
        //  this.books.push(new Book(bookLike.title, bookLike.author));
        //});
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: @EmileAchadde The question was about making isEqual work or making indexOfBook to work ?

Comment: The question was : how to make isEqual work when defined in Book class.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase returns some data, but it's just an object: you need to create a `Book` *instance* out of that data with `new Book()`.

```
firebase.database().ref('/books')
        .on('value', 
            (data: DataSnapshot) => 
            {
                this.books = data.val() ? data.val().map(book => new Book(book[0], book[1])) : [];
                this.emitBooks();
            }
        );
    }
```

Since I don't know what Firebase returns in `val()`, this is just an example use assuming the data contains an array of `[author, title]` tuples, but you get the idea. Perhaps it's actually `new Book(book.author, book.title)`...

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what the map operator is doing.
A console.log of the books array in constructor gives this output :
Array books is  
```(5) […]
​0: Object { author: "Victor Hugo", synopsis: "", title: "Les Misérables" }
​1: Object { author: "John Le Carré", synopsis: "zazrt", title: "A Legacy of Spies" }
​etc ...```
I do not known how and where to do this cast. (I am very new in Angular)

Comment: I tried this : 
`this.books = data.val() ? data.val().map(book => new Book(book.title, book.author)) : [];`
 which compiles but gives the same error

Comment: I did :
```const bookIndex = this.books.findIndex((a_book) => {
  const the_book = new Book(a_book.title, a_book.author); 
  return the_book.isEqual (book)}```
to cast the_book and use the isEqual method. It is far from elegant. Could someone give me a better answer ? (And also, how to format this text ?)

Comment: @EmileAchadde I've kept this answer for historical purposes, but added a second answer that rewrites the code with interfaces and which simplifies the search.

Answer (score 2):

Creating lots of new class instances, which the current code requires, is laborious and probably unnecessary.

Here is an alternative that uses `interface`s instead (which are not emitted to JavaScript at all) and a much simplified index search.

```
export interface Book {
    title: string;
    author: string;
}
```

and then in the service, a small change to cast your return as a `Book[]`:

```
this.books = data.val() ? (data.val() as Book[]) : [];
```

Then you can use a helper function and forego the class entirely. Before, it used a mix of arrow functions and braced return statements, and the isEqual helper was unnecessary, as the whole thing can be reduced to:

```
indexOfBook = (needle: Book) => this.books.findIndex(
    book => book.author == needle.author && book.title == needle.title
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution.